# Configure cloudwatch -> elastic search through java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elasticsearch

If you look at the following link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html, there is a mechanism to associate a log group with an elastic search domain. Do you know this can be done via the java aws sdk so that it can be automated in a running application?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the EC domain is already created.

1. Create IAM role that allows Cloudwatch logs access to ES.

   ```
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",

   "Statement": [
       {
           "Action": [
               "es:*"
           ],
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:123456789012:domain/streaming-logs/*"
       }
     ]

   }
   ```
2. [Create the log group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/CreateLogStreamResult.html)
3. [Create the Subscription filter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/SubscriptionFilter.html)